# In-app purchases are “in review” while the app binary itself is still “waiting for review”? What does it mean?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

At start: Date Last Binary Submitted: September 19, 2013

In-App Purchase status is "In Review" but app status is "Waiting For Review" What does it mean? Is this normal? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm in the same status as yours. How long was your review process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's normal, apple make a look for In-App Purchases too, to make sure all of them are valid, and ok. After your app status becomes ready for sale, it will work fine ( of course only if your IAP's status are: Approved )

edit:

review times are always different, 6-10 or 6-15 days. Here is a page where are some actual information about the review times, by the developers. I use it everytime when I upload my new app. [review times](http://appreviewtimes.com)

Comment: Thanks for answer, so i must wait but how long

Comment: usually the review time is 6-10  days

Comment: I edited my answer, pls if I answered your question, accept it.